# Find a value in column of lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns A & B, B is column of lists and A is a string, I want to search a value in the column B and get the corresponding value in column A. For ex :

```
     category         zones
0  category_1  [zn_1, zn_2]
1  category_2        [zn_3]
2  category_3        [zn_4]
3  category_4  [zn_5, zn_6]
```

If the `input = 'zn_1'`, how can i get a response back as `'category_1'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.contains` and filter `category` values

```
inputvalue='zn_1'
df[df.zones.str.contains(inputvalue)]['category']

#If didnt want an array

inputvalue='zn_1'
list(df[df.zones.str.contains(inputvalue)]['category'].values)[0]
```